# Error- ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'name' for Review

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, activemodel

When I run:

```
rails db:seed
```

in the command line, I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'name' for Review..........................................................
```

I also get the same error when I run:

```
rails db:seed
```

seeds.rb

```
movie = Movie.find_by(title: 'Iron Man')
movie.reviews.create!(name: "Roger Ebert", stars: 3, comment: "I laughed, I cried, I spilled my popcorn!")
movie.reviews.create!(name: "Gene Siskel", stars: 5, comment: "I'm a better reviewer than he is.")
movie.reviews.create!(name: "Peter Travers", stars: 4, comment: "It's been years since a movie superhero was this fierce and this funny.")

movie = Movie.find_by(title: 'Superman')
movie.reviews.create!(name: "Elvis Mitchell", stars: 5, comment: "It's a bird, it's a plane, it's a blockbuster!")


Genre.create!(name: "Action")
Genre.create!(name: "Comedy")
Genre.create!(name: "Drama")
Genre.create!(name: "Romance")
Genre.create!(name: "Thriller")
Genre.create!(name: "Fantasy")
Genre.create!(name: "Documentary")
Genre.create!(name: "Adventure")
Genre.create!(name: "Animation")
Genre.create!(name: "Sci-Fi")
```

Here is my schema filee [sic]:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20181218222845) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "characterizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "movie_id"
    t.bigint "genre_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["genre_id"], name: "index_characterizations_on_genre_id"
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_characterizations_on_movie_id"
  end

  create_table "favorites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "movie_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_movie_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "genres", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "rating"
    t.decimal "total_gross"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.date "released_on"
    t.string "cast"
    t.string "director"
    t.string "duration"
    t.string "image_file_name", default: ""
    t.string "image_content_type"
    t.integer "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string "main_image"
    t.string "slug"
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "stars"
    t.text "comment"
    t.bigint "movie_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_movie_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "characterizations", "genres"
  add_foreign_key "characterizations", "movies"
  add_foreign_key "favorites", "movies"
  add_foreign_key "favorites", "users"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "movies"
end
```

Comment: Post your schema too. Maybe run `rails db:create`  and `rails db:migrate`.

Comment: @well-i-better-get-rolling the database was already created and migrated. Thanks though

Comment: there is no `name` field in your reviews schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reviews` table does not have a `name` column, which is what Rails is telling you.

I don’t know how your app works, but I do see a `user_id` column on the `reviews` table, and the `users` table has a `name` column, so I imagine you need to create a user using that name attribute, and then pass the user into the review that you’re creating.

Without seeing your `Review` and `User` model, I can’t speak for sure.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you'll need to create a migration & run it to add the `name` field to your `reviews` table:

```
rails generate migration AddNameToReviews name:string
rails db:migrate
```

This should fix your reported error.